# Keep getting Dependency Installation error on Autocode when trying to use a Node.JS library

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, autocode

On Autocode, I am making a Discord bot that connects the user (via mentioning in a message with my bot) to CharacterAI. I am doing so by using an unofficial Node.JS API found on Github, linked here: https://github.com/realcoloride/node_characterai/
It can also be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node_characterai

I added the dependency to my project with the Configure Dependencies section, and only have the following dependencies installed:
[image: Dependencies in project]

I only get the error whenever the `node_characterai` dependency is installed (whenever I uninstall it, the error goes away despite me keeping `const CharacterAI = require('node_characterai');` in my code)

Is it possible for me to use this dependency without the error? If so, how could I remove this error? Otherwise, what else could I possibly use to connect my Discord bot to CharacterAI?